# Should we be quoting so much Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying from online sources](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/copying-from-online-sources)
>   [Should we allow Wikipedia to be referenced as an academic source in answers?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-we-allow-wikipedia-to-be-referenced-as-an-academic-source-in-answers)

I'm a bit worried already that we are just practicing google-fu and pasting quotes from wikipedia.  Wikipedia provides excellent answers in many circumstances, but if a Q & A is just:

> Question:  Who invented [thing]?
>
> Answer: According to Wikipedia:
>
> > Wikipedia copy/paste

then I worry that this board will be little more than [lmgtfy](http://lmgtfy.com/).

Is this a legitimate concern, and if so, what can we do to mitigate it?

Comment: I'm voting to close, because we already have a topic on copying, and I think it should be about copying in general and not just Wiki.

Comment: I think it should remain open because my question does a better job of laying out the problem and giving an example.

Comment: I think this is a fantastic question, but also potentially a duplicate as Jacob has referenced.

Comment: @ChristopherRayl: ...but posting a duplicate question will only split the discussion and the answers. If the other question can be improved, please feel free to improve it.